# PayPal Merchant SDK GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetails not returning buyer's email or phone number

Tags: paypal

I'm using the PayPal Merchant SDK for .NET (v 2.15.117) and am trying to retrieve the shipping address info, customer's email address, and phone number from the GetExpressCheckoutDetailsRequestType.GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetails call. The shipping address is populated as expected but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to get the buyer's email or phone number. At a minimum we have to have the email to communicate about the order (ie tracking emails).

I see a BuyerMarketingEmail property but it is null and I am under the impression that is an optional email the buyer can choose to provide. For phone, I see a PayerInfo.ContactPhone property but that is also null (and I'm less concerned about having that but it would be nice for customer service issues or to give to ground shippers like FedEx).

I am using the PayPal sandbox if that matters.

What am I missing?

```
var getExpressCheckoutDetails = new GetExpressCheckoutDetailsReq();

var getExpressCheckoutDetailsRequest = new GetExpressCheckoutDetailsRequestType(token);

getExpressCheckoutDetails.GetExpressCheckoutDetailsRequest = getExpressCheckoutDetailsRequest;

var service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService();

paypalResponse = service.GetExpressCheckoutDetails(getExpressCheckoutDetails);

if (paypalResponse != null)
{
    //Success values check for a matching PayerID to validate the token response
    if (paypalResponse.Ack.ToString().Trim().ToUpper().Equals("SUCCESS") &&
        PayerID == paypalResponse.GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetails.PayerInfo.PayerID)
    {
        checkout.ShippingInfo.ShippingName = paypalResponse.GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetails.PayerInfo.Address.Name;
        checkout.ShippingInfo.ShippingAddress1 = paypalResponse.GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetails.PayerInfo.Address.Street1;
        checkout.ShippingInfo.ShippingAddress2 = paypalResponse.GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetails.PayerInfo.Address.Street2;
        checkout.ShippingInfo.ShippingCity = paypalResponse.GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetails.PayerInfo.Address.CityName;
        checkout.ShippingInfo.ShippingState = paypalResponse.GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetails.PayerInfo.Address.StateOrProvince;
        checkout.ShippingInfo.ShippingZip = paypalResponse.GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetails.PayerInfo.Address.PostalCode;
        checkout.ShippingInfo.ShippingCountry = paypalResponse.GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetails.PayerInfo.Address.Country.ToString();

        //these next two are always null
        checkout.BillingInfo.Email = paypalResponse.GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetails.BuyerMarketingEmail;
        checkout.ShippingInfo.PhoneNumber = paypalResponse.GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetails.PayerInfo.ContactPhone;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Digging through PayPal support articles, I did come across a VB.net example that showed how to get the email address for the buyer. In the example above, it would look like: `checkout.BillingInfo.Email = paypalResponse.GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetails.PayerInfo.Payer;` Makes sense considering the buyer's username is their email address. No luck getting a phone number yet though. The ContactPhone property seems obvious - maybe this is a Sandbox issue?

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd post an answer to wrap this up -

As stated above in my comment to the original question, the email address of the buyer is `PayerInfo.Payer`.

Also, suddenly/magically, `PayerInfo.ContactPhone` began returning the phone number instead of null. I can only chalk that up to something in the Sandbox environment or my sandbox user account.